# Avoid escaping underscores and bracketing URLs when converting from Rmd to md

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm attempting to convert an RMarkdown file to Markdown in order to be posted to a Github pages (jekyll) website. As figure captions require extensions, I'm using the the method suggested by the jekyll theme to add captions. The problem is that when parsing from `.Rmd` to `.md` the code for the figure is not kept verbatim, and is parsed in way that breaks jekyll.

Take this MWE:

```
---
title: "MWE"
output: 
  md_document:
    preserve_yaml: TRUE
    variant: markdown_strict+backtick_code_blocks
---
## Test title

Text goes here.

{% include figure image_path="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Macaca_nigra_self-portrait_large.jpg" caption="Caption goes here." %}
```

This is parsed as:

```
---
title: "MWE"
output: 
  md_document:
    preserve_yaml: TRUE
    variant: markdown_strict+backtick_code_blocks
---

Test title
----------

Text goes here.

{% include figure
image\_path="<https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Macaca_nigra_self-portrait_large.jpg>"
caption="Caption goes here." %}
```

Note the text at the end inside the curly brackets, specifically the underscore in `image_path` is now escaped and the URL is bracketed. I'd like to keep this code verbatim:

```
{% include figure image_path="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Macaca_nigra_self-portrait_large.jpg" caption="Caption goes here." %}
```

I'm using `R v3.3.3`, `rmarkdown v1.2`, `pandoc v1.17.2`, and RStudio `v1.0.136`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to escape it so that Rmarkdown passes it through literally.

Comment: why not go directly from .Rmd to html?

Comment: I didn't have that specific issue - but there is a document available on passing things verbatim through RMarkdown - maybe it's helpful: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_verbatim.html